# Publish pages/posts as HTML?

Tags: html, customization

We're looking to use a plugin or custom setup for authors to create pages or posts and publish them as single HTML files. The file could be saved on the server in a specific directory or have a download button from within the editor.

So far we have found 2 plugins that almost achieve this function:

[WP Static Output](http://leonstafford.com/wordpress-static-html-output-plugin/)

[Really Static](http://www.php-welt.net/really-static/index.html)

Both work fairly similar but need admin access to generate. They also create the files in the following fashion:

dir-on-server/page-title/index.html

*where I would need*

dir-on-server/page-title/page-title.html

Any thoughts on this? Has anyone done something similar? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Plugin recommendation is off-topic now. Maybe a combination of [`wp_remote_get`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_get) and [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

`wget --mirror` as part of a cron job may do what you need.

The lack of dynamic content will give the following issues:

- comment support (which I delegate to disqus)
- search support (which can be delegated to Google site search, though I haven't implemented that myself)
- delete of posts no longer work
- your permalinks should not use the ?postid= form.